# "loading" div automatically appended when using cordova (phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using cordova for mobile app development on android platform.
I have this html code in www/index.html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <script src="cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css"/>

</head>
    <body id="body" class="body">
        <div id="box" class="bodyBlack">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why but when I am running this app (also when just opening on pc browser) i am having this div appended at the bottom of the page:

```
<div ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default>
    <span ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default></span>
        <h1>loading</h1>
```

Here is the content of main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') == 'bodyBlack'){
            $(this).removeClass('bodyBlack');
            $(this).addClass('bodyWhite');
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass('bodyWhite');
            $(this).addClass('bodyBlack');
        }
    });
});
```

Why and from where dose it getting from? how I am preventing it to do so?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a "Loading Message" generated by jQuery Mobile, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245360/jquerymobile-loading-message-theme). So jQuery Mobile is loading something (and cant't find it, perhaps). Please post the content of your `main.js` file if you're still having trouble!

Comment: the main.js is now part of the question

Comment: OK so it seems that jQuery Mobile is trying to load something by default. It's been a while since I have used it so I'm not sure what exactly it is, but that ``div`` is definitely generated by jQM!

Comment: I have found the solution on in the link you have given me