# How to override jquery mobile css when using apache cordova for android

Tags: android, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building an Android App using Apache Cordova (PhoneGap). I just made the homepage of the app (which takes content from a website and loads into the mobile), and saw that there are two texts *"Loading"* at the footer location in this mobile page.

I read from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245360/jquerymobile-loading-message-theme) that this is because I did not link the jquery mobile css in the app. So I downloaded jquery mobile css from their site, and then by linking this css, the Loading text issue was resolved. It is no longer displayed.

However, all my css and formating of the mobile page was overwritten by this jquery mobile css, and the page looks horrible now.

I just want to know how to override the jquery mobile css settings, and let the app just use my custom css alone, but at the same time, I do not want the `"Loading"` text to be there.

This is the code that I have -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

</head>
<body>
...
--- my code goes here ---
...

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> // this is jquery mobile
</body>
</html>
<body>
```

How do I do this? I do NOT want any loader, basically.

Comment: Remove the loading div and use your CSS `$('div.ui-loader').remove();`. This div is placed at the bottom of the page, removing it will solve your problem without the need to use JQM CSS.

Comment: @Omar- Thanks, however I did not quite get your comment. Where should I put the Javascript code that you provided? Where is this unwanted div present? How do I locate it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This div is located at the bottom of each page before `</body>`. You could put it for each page, but try this first `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () { $('div.ui-loader').remove(); });`. This should work for all pages. Try it and let me know the result.

Comment: @Omar- thanks. I am quite a newbie. Should I put the code that you gave in last comment just like that at the end of the page, before body closing tag?

Comment: You can place it anywhere between inside body.

Comment: @Omar - I tried putting inside the jQuery ready function, and also under <script></script> before the </body> tag. Both did not work. Mine is just a single page app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28214/discussion-between-omar-and-kallakafar)